# Restlet 2.2 + Spring integration

Tags: spring, hibernate, restlet

I have a fully functional Restlet app that I am trying to add Spring Data Jpa + Hibernate.

Firstly I need to get Spring and Restlet playing together.

The example below is from the Restlet docs, it is trying to set a root property on the Application Class, I can not find this root property, it must be from and old version of the API.

Can someone please post an example of Spring and Restlet 2.2 config, this is very frustrating.

```
<bean id="basecampAppliction" class="classpath to Application class">
    <property name="root" ref="router" />
</bean>
```

Also, all the examples I have found rely on Spring doing the routing, I would like to keep the routing in the Application code if that is possible.

Comment: The issue above has been resolved, seems the web docs are out of date, this changed from root to inboundRoot

Answer (score 0):

The docs on the Restlet web site are out of date, please see fix above.